# conditional format modify defined object error 1004

Tags: vba, formatting

I need your help once again.
I wrote down below code but it returns to me

> Error 1004

```
Sub ModifCF7codici()
'On Error GoTo ErrGest
Worksheets(3).Select
Worksheets(3).Unprotect Password:="ponzio"

'Application.EnableEvents = False
A = Cells.FormatConditions.Count
Worksheets(3).Cells.FormatConditions(A).Modify Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A1=0"
    'Formula1:="=
'=$S" & (4 - 3) & "<$" & "S" & (3 - 2))

'ErrGest:
'Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub
```

any idea on how to beat it? thankx

Answer (score 0):

Your code might work, depending on what your sheet looks like. If the last format condition happens to be one that accepts Type=Expression and Formula1 as  parameters, it will work. If not, you will get the error you see.

Add a watch with the expression `Worksheets(3).Cells.FormatConditions(A)` and look at what type it is. If it says `FormatCondition` you are good to go, but if says DataBar or something else, your code will have to deal with that instead.